# Custom events data in Firebase Events

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a loggin mechanizm,which logs custom events to the firebase.

```
Event logged. Event name, event params: Session, {
"_o" = app;
deviceId = "21957A5C-5344-4D93-BCFB-3D01EDCC8886";
type = "Manual Logout";
userId = 2;}
```

It successfully logs events,I can see keys of my custom data, but I cant see values for that keys
For example here is what I see for

> deviceId

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Firebase presents aggregated data, in most cases. Secondly, in case of custom events, value will not be available in the dashboard for you to see.

Your best shot if you are going for free is to use pre-existing event template and fit your events to suit your need, such as:

```
static func levelChange(level: Int, gameIndex: Int) {
        Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventLevelUp, parameters: [AnalyticsParameterLevel: level as NSNumber,
                                                               AnalyticsParameterCharacter: String(gameIndex) as NSString])
    }
```

Here I have used the pre-existing event template, though my event is not actually a level-up, but at least I am able to see values (aggregated) in the dashboard, as below:

[image]

Alternatively, which I have now moved onto, is to activate **Blaze plan** within Firebase, wherein all your raw events will be pushed to **BigQuery** DB, from where you can access whatever custom event parameters you've stored.